# change property to element child

Tags: html, css

I have a parent div with an opacity property of 0.5 and the child is an arrow that I want to have opacity 1. The problem is that the child element always inherits 0.5 from the parent. How can I change the opacity of the arrow to 1 ?. The parent element, ie, the rectangle must retain the opacity 0.5 and the child must have opacity 1.

```
  <div class='contenedor_flecha_prev'>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left flecha_izqu" ></i>
 </div>

  .contenedor_flecha_prev{
    position: fixed;
    height: 80%;
    width: 8%;
    background: black;
    bottom: 10%;
    min-width: 35px;
    left: 0px;
    z-index: 90;
    opacity:0.5;
    cursor:pointer;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  }

  .fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu{
      font-size: 55px;
      color: white;
      position: absolute;
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      -webkit-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      -moz-transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
      opacity: 1;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2wonjwde/

Comment: Chrome on windows 10 has the fiddle working the way you want it to. What browser are you on?

Comment: If it's just the background on the parent you want to be opaque, use `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` instead of `black` and remove `opacity: 0.5`

Comment: No it doesn't. Do `body{background:red;}` to test it.

Comment: @mikeg542 windows 7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can introduce a common parent that is the main size of this block, then take your arrow out of the current element and put it in the common parent and set the opacity of the 2 elements separately.

```css
body {
  background: red;
}

.parent {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80%;
  width: 8%;
  bottom: 10%;
  min-width: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 90;
}

.contenedor_flecha_prev {
  background: black;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0.5;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu {
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="parent">
  <div class='contenedor_flecha_prev'>
  </div>
  <i class="fa fa-chevron-left flecha_izqu"></i>
</div>
```

But like I said in the comments, if it's just the background on the parent you want to be opaque, use `background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);` instead of `black` and remove `opacity: 0.5`

```css
body {
background: red;
}

.contenedor_flecha_prev {
  position: fixed;
  height: 80%;
  width: 8%;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  bottom: 10%;
  min-width: 35px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 90;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
  transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}

.fa.fa-chevron-left.flecha_izqu {
  font-size: 55px;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -moz-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <div class='contenedor_flecha_prev'>
      <i class="fa fa-chevron-left flecha_izqu" ></i>
  </div>
```

Comment: what is the best way? Why does it work with  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5)?

Comment: @yavg use `rgba`, it's simpler, less markup. Do you know what `rgba()` is? If not it's RGB with alpha transparency where the last value is the opacity as an integer between 0 (invisible) - 1 (fully visible)